# ReactJS router not working

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I can't seem to solve this or find an answer.  I have a basic React Router setup that works for the IndexRoute (localhost:8080/ or localhost:8080 renders).  The templates nest the way I want, but the sub routes '/test1, /test2, and /test3 don't render. I get `Cannot GET /test1`  Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from "react-router";

import Index from "./pages/Index";
import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Test1 from "./pages/Test1";
import Test2 from "./pages/Test2";
import Test3 from "./pages/Test3";

const app = document.getElementById('main');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={ browserHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Index}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="test1" component={Test1}></Route>
      <Route path="test2" component={Test2}></Route>
      <Route path="test3" component={Test3}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
app);
```

I have tried renaming the paths and components without the numbers and have also tried `path='/test1'`

I'm guessing it is a small bug.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you define the routes in your `<Layout>` component by using `this.props.children` or similar?

Comment: Please show `Layout` and `Index` components' code

Comment: Here is a gist https://gist.github.com/WebRuin/d60946dbfaa5a3a1ca42d4fe1549601e

Comment: This should cover your problem (ctrl+f "catch-all") http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually

Comment: I can get to the link via `<link to='test1'>Link</Link>`.  But when I go to the links directly I get the error.

Comment: I know. Read the answer in the question that I linked. Your server is not recognizing the URL `/test1` so it is 404ing. You will need to add a catch all that returns your `index.html` for all requested URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your server config misses this part:

```
// All routes should resolve with `index.html`
app.get('*', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```

Change `public` to wherever you have your main `index.html`.

You can also use [express-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback), if you're using `express`:

```
app.use(staticFallback('index.html', { root: buildDir }));
```